# Listen to a list and do something whenever it is appended

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have an API listening to incoming requests and dumping them into a list.
On a separate process, I'd like to trigger some kind of operation whenever the list is appended. I tried instantiating a new Process (from multiprocessing), but it doesn't update the state of the array once it starts.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

procs = []

def separateProcess(start, counter):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("length of the list from separate Process: "+str(len(procs)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("program started")

    counter = 0
    Process(target=separateProcess, args=(counter, counter)).start()
    print("program end")
    while True:
        counter += 1
        newstring = "string "+str(counter)
        procs.append(newstring)
        print("length of the list from main: " + str(len(procs)))
        time.sleep(2)
```

here's the output:

```
length of the list from main: 1
length of the list from separate Process: 0
length of the list from main: 2
length of the list from separate Process: 0
length of the list from separate Process: 0
length of the list from main: 3
length of the list from separate Process: 0
length of the list from separate Process: 0
```

Comment: It would need to be a thread, not a process.

Comment: @alaniwi it would actually need to be a process

Comment: why not to use a queue?

Comment: I can look into that. It'd be great if you could add a few lines to show that would work in this basic example. @Marat

Comment: my bad, if you need a separate process it has to be something more substantial, like Celery or AMPQ. Processes get a copy of parent's memory but changes are obviously not reflected there. Built-in queue (the easiest solution) will only work with threads

Comment: @Marat, actually the solution came from multiprocessing.Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new child process is created, it gets a **copy** of the parent's address space however any subsequent changes (either by parent or child) are not reflected in the memory of the other process. They each have their own private address space.

You can create a [Manager()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) and use its shared [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) object instead:

```
import time
  
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

def separateProcess(start, counter):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("length of the list from separate Process: "+str(len(procs)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    procs = m.list()

    print("program started")

    counter = 0
    Process(target=separateProcess, args=(counter, counter)).start()
    print("program end")
    while True:
        counter += 1
        newstring = "string "+str(counter)
        procs.append(newstring)
        print("length of the list from main: " + str(len(procs)))
        time.sleep(2)
```

There is some overhead with this approach as it will a spawn child process to host the `Manager` server.

In case you can adjust your worker process logic to use a queue instead, here is an example:

```
import random
import time

from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Process, Queue


def worker(q):
    for item in iter(q.get, 'STOP'):
        t = random.uniform(1, 5)
        print(f'START item: {item}')
        time.sleep(t)
        print(f'END item: {item}, ({t:.3f}s)')


def main():
    cpus = cpu_count()
    q = Queue()

    for i in range(5):
        q.put(i)

    for i in range(cpus):
        Process(target=worker, args=(q,)).start()

    for i in range(cpus):
        q.put('STOP')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Than you so much! I went with queue. The cpu_count() doesn't seem to influence or limit the number of processes I can spawn though. Why is that worth considering?

Comment: @AndreiȚăranu if the workload is CPU-intensive, spawning more processes than physical CPU cores will actually decrease the performance.